# Positive-definite block matrix with constant block sums

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

Given two natural numbers $n$ and $m$, suppose that $A$
is an $nm\times nm$
real nonnegative matrix. Seeing $A$
as a block matrix where each block has size $m\times m$, suppose that the sum of the entries in each block is $1$. Can $A$
be positive-definite? Notice that making $A$
positive-*semi*definite is easy, for example we can let $A=\frac{1}{m}J_n\otimes I_m$. Also, notice that for $m=1$
the answer is no, as the only matrix satisfying the constraints is the all-one matrix.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot possibly be positive definite because $x^TAx=0$ when
$$
x=(\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{m},\underbrace{-1,\ldots,-1}_{m},0,\ldots,0)^T.
$$

Comment: Thanks! So this gives us that $0$ must be an eigenvalue with multiplicity at least $n-1$. Is it possible that the multiplicity is exactly $n-1$?

Comment: @GaussJordan Yes. This occurs when the diagonal sub-blocks are $\frac{1}{m}I_m$ and the off-diagonal sub-blocks are $\frac{1}{m^2}J_m$.